# How to get all commits in GitHub?

Tags: java, git, github

I'm using `GitHub API` to get Commits.

```
GET /repos/:owner/:repo/commits
```

https://api.github.com/repos/nasa/mct/commits?branch=incoming&since=2014-08-26T23:43:48Z

For example, `owner:nasa project:mct`

I want to get all commits in branch:incoming and since that time.But it seems only returns one commit(should be 9 commits).What can I do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've got it.I should check [Github API](https://developer.github.com/v3/#pagination) more carefully.

You can use pagination to get what you want.

By default,It only displays the default number of items.